# Azure blobs how to await for blob creation before proceeding?

Tags: node.js, azure, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I am using NodeJS and the azure storage sdk, I am having an issue that the files I am uploading to my blobs are being created as 0kb files unless I add an intermediary function to delay it so that the blob is created before the upload happens. I get the same results when uploading as a stream or as a local file from the azure-storage sdk.

I have the following function:

```
async function uploadToBlob(localFilePath) {


        //ACTIVATE CREDENTIALS AND CONTAINER
    const credentials = new SharedKeyCredential(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);
    const pipeline = StorageURL.newPipeline(credentials);
    const serviceURL = new ServiceURL(`https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`, pipeline);
    const containerURL = ContainerURL.fromServiceURL(serviceURL, containerName);  
    const aborter = Aborter.timeout(30 * ONE_MINUTE);

    //UPLOAD IMAGE
    var blobName = localFilePath.substring(localFilePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 );
    var fullBlobName = category + "/" + subcategory + "/" + blobName;
    var blobURL = await BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, fullBlobName);

    await uploadImage(aborter, containerURL, localFilePath, blobURL)


}
```

where I get the blobURL var by doing an await on BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL
and as you can see has an await on it and there is also an await on the call to uploadImage.

Then here is the function that is called and that calls the uploadFileToBlockBlob from azures sdk:

```
//UPLOAD IMAGE NO-STREAM
async function uploadImage(aborter, containerURL, filePath, blobURL, blobName) {
    try {
        filePath = path.resolve(filePath);

         //THIS LINE MAKES IT WORK
        await showBlobNames(aborter, containerURL);

        addToDB(blobName, blobURL.url);


        console.log("Calling uploadFileToBlockBlob with filePath: " + filePath + 
                    " and blobURL: "+ blobURL.url)
        return await uploadFileToBlockBlob(aborter, filePath, blobURL);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

In this last function I added

```
await showBlobNames(aborter, containerURL);
```

and that made it work.

It seems like before that the file was being uploaded before the blob was created and the images were being uploaded with the right name and into the blob but as 0kb files, and adding this function delays it so that the Blob can be created.

I don't understand why the previous awaits don't make the upload wait till the blob is created.  I also tried putting the upload call inside a callback function but so it would be executed when the blob is created but doesnt seem to be supported (doesnt call the callback function)

I have it working adding the call to showBlobNames but I feel like my code shouldnt have to rely on this and I want to learn why the await's arent working.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i am making connection  and executing CRUD operation

```js
    await containerURL.create(aborter);
    console.log(`Container: "${containerName}" is created`);

    await blockBlobURL.upload(aborter, content, content.length);
    console.log(`Blob "${blobName}" is uploaded`);
    
    await uploadLocalFile(aborter, containerURL, localFilePath);
    console.log(`Local file "${localFilePath}" is uploaded`);

    await uploadStream(aborter, containerURL, localFilePath);
    console.log(`Local file "${localFilePath}" is uploaded as a stream`);

    console.log(`Blobs in "${containerName}" container:`);
    await showBlobNames(aborter, containerURL);
```

and here is the function implementation for the same.

```js
async function showContainerNames(aborter, serviceURL) {

    let response;
    let marker;

    do {
        response = await serviceURL.listContainersSegment(aborter, marker);
        marker = response.marker;
        for(let container of response.containerItems) {
            console.log(` - ${ container.name }`);
        }
    } while (marker);
}

async function uploadLocalFile(aborter, containerURL, filePath) {

    filePath = path.resolve(filePath);

    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
    const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, fileName);

    return await uploadFileToBlockBlob(aborter, filePath, blockBlobURL);
}

async function uploadStream(aborter, containerURL, filePath) {

    filePath = path.resolve(filePath);

    const fileName = path.basename(filePath).replace('.md', '-stream.md');
    const blockBlobURL = BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(containerURL, fileName);

    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {
      highWaterMark: FOUR_MEGABYTES,
    });

    const uploadOptions = {
        bufferSize: FOUR_MEGABYTES,
        maxBuffers: 5,
    };

    return await uploadStreamToBlockBlob(
                    aborter, 
                    stream, 
                    blockBlobURL, 
                    uploadOptions.bufferSize, 
                    uploadOptions.maxBuffers);
}

async function showBlobNames(aborter, containerURL) {

    let response;
    let marker;

    do {
        response = await containerURL.listBlobFlatSegment(aborter);
        marker = response.marker;
        for(let blob of response.segment.blobItems) {
            console.log(` - ${ blob.name }`);
        }
    } while (marker);
}
```

I have used javascript SDK 10 for azure storage in my example and it worked perfectly for me. For source repo, please refer  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-storage-js-v10-quickstart

Hope it helps.

**MV**

Comment: Hi Thanks, that seems pretty much like the code from the azure docs, I started with that but then modified it a bit to suit my needs.  Like I said mine also works fine if I do showcontainer or showblobnames after the upload functions like in your code, I just feel await should take care of that and not need those functions to delay the upload.

Comment: I tried without await showBlobNames(aborter, containerURL);  and it worked without that. P.S. - I am using SDK 10 for the same.

Comment: Not sure mine also worked when I had my code like yours from the sdk, but i am trying to figure out why now I need the extra call to make it work. I am also running in a loop quite a few uploads one after another but I dont think that is the issue  when I tried just one it also happened.